# Prometheus Blackbox exporter unknown timeouts

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Im having an issue with the Prometheus Blackbox exporter. Somehow i receive a lot of timeouts since i updated to the most recent version.

As you can see in below screenshot there is a massive spike on one of the endpoints and probe duration. However there is no such spike in the HTTP duration where that should reflect the actual http call to the application?

[image: Grafana dashboard]

Im stuck on where to look next though so i hope that someone has an idea where to look and point me to the right direction.

Best,
Pim